# Free IntPtr allocated memory after promoting the pointer

Tags: c#, c++

I'm using IntPtr in C#, to get array of object from C++ project.

To do that, i allocated the memory needed with Marshal.AllocHGlobal method, and i'm copying the full array in C++ into the ptr.

The thing is I am promoting the pointer, to move to the next object in the array.

My question is:
Do i have to restore the first value of the IntPtr, before using the Marshal.FreeHGlobal method?

Here is the code

```
public List<DirEntry> getDirEntries()
    {
            int dirEntrySize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DirEntry));
            int bufferSize = 28 * dirEntrySize;
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
            CppToCsharpAdapter.getDirEntries(this.myDiskPointer, buffer);

            DirEntry dirEntry = new DirEntry();
            List<DirEntry> dirEntries = new List<DirEntry>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
            {
                Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, dirEntry);
                buffer += dirEntrySize;
            }

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
            return dirEntries;
    }
```

Comment: If this doesn't crash your program then there's something seriously wrong with your operating system.

Comment: Your right, i don't even tried to run the program without reseting the ptr to the first value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a copy of the original pointer which can be used later use. In this case, it is called current:

```
    public List<DirEntry> getDirEntries()
    {
        int dirEntrySize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DirEntry));
        int bufferSize = 28 * dirEntrySize;
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
        CppToCsharpAdapter.getDirEntries(this.myDiskPointer, buffer);

        IntPtr current = buffer;

        DirEntry dirEntry = new DirEntry();
        List<DirEntry> dirEntries = new List<DirEntry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
        {
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(current, dirEntry);
            current += dirEntrySize;
        }

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        return dirEntries;
    }
```

However, there is another possibility without using an explicit copy of your pointer by using `IntPtr.Add()`:

```
    public List<DirEntry> getDirEntries()
    {
        int dirEntrySize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DirEntry));
        int bufferSize = 28 * dirEntrySize;
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
        CppToCsharpAdapter.getDirEntries(this.myDiskPointer, buffer);

        DirEntry dirEntry = new DirEntry();
        List<DirEntry> dirEntries = new List<DirEntry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
        {
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr.Add(buffer, i * dirEntrySize), dirEntry);
        }

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        return dirEntries;
    }
```

Please keep in mind, that your code contains a potential memory leek. You should wrap your code in a try/finally block. In the finally block you free the memory block again if the pointer is not zero:

```
    public List<DirEntry> getDirEntries()
    {
        int dirEntrySize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DirEntry));
        int bufferSize = 28 * dirEntrySize;
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);

        try
        {
            CppToCsharpAdapter.getDirEntries(this.myDiskPointer, buffer);

            DirEntry dirEntry = new DirEntry();
            List<DirEntry> dirEntries = new List<DirEntry>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
            {
                Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr.Add(buffer, i * dirEntrySize), dirEntry);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        }


        return dirEntries;
    }
```

Comment: I think after free the memory, need to set buffer to 0.

even after doing that

    finally
            {
                if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
            }

the ptr steel not Zero.
And if it will repeat this code, the program will crash.

Comment: @avicohh nope. you don't have to set the pointer to zero. After the memory is freed, the pointer is no longer used and therefore, it is not required to set it to zero.

Comment: @avicohh where does it crash?

Comment: for example in this code the program crash. `IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1000); while (buffer != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);` because after the memory free buffer it steel not zero.

Comment: `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);` will not set the pointer to zero ! The memory area the pointer is pointing to, after it is freed, should not be accessed any more. So you should do as i wrote in my answer: `if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);`